# Running a parallelized numba-function with 1 thread is faster than the non-parallelized version

Tags: python, parallel-processing, numba

I have to perform a lot of small matrix multiplications and tried to parallelize the code with `numba`. If I compile the same function with `parallel=True` one time and with `parallel=False` the other, the parallelized function is faster even if I set `set_num_threads(1)`.

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
from time import time
from numba import njit, prange, set_num_threads
import numpy as np

@contextmanager
def time_it(msg=""):
    tic = time()
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        toc = time()
        print(f'Computation time: {(toc - tic) * 1e3:.2f} ms \t({msg})')

@njit('float64[:,:,:,::1],float64[:,:,:,::1],float64[:,:,:,::1]', parallel=False)
def matrix_mult_single(a, b, out):
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        for j in range(a.shape[1]):
            for k in range(11):
                for l in range(11):
                    for m in range(11):
                        out[i, j, k, m] += a[i, j, k, l] * b[i, j, l, m]

@njit('float64[:,:,:,::1],float64[:,:,:,::1],float64[:,:,:,::1]', parallel=True)
def matrix_mult_parallel(a, b, out):
    for i in prange(a.shape[0]):
        for j in range(a.shape[1]):
            for l in range(11):
                for k in range(11):
                    for m in range(11):
                        out[i, j, k, m] += a[i, j, k, l] * b[i, j, l, m]

def matmult(a, b, out):
    np.matmul(a, b, out=out)


A = np.random.rand(201, 201, 11, 11)
B = np.random.rand(201, 201, 11, 11)

with time_it("numpy"):
    np.matmul(A, B, out=np.zeros_like(A))

matrix_mult_single(A, B, np.zeros_like(A))
with time_it("numba - single"):
    matrix_mult_single(A, B, np.zeros_like(A))

set_num_threads(1)
matrix_mult_parallel(A, B, np.zeros_like(A))
with time_it("numba - parallel"):
    matrix_mult_parallel(A, B, np.zeros_like(A))
```

```py
# Output (openblas)
Computation time: 16.68 ms  (numpy)
Computation time: 43.93 ms  (numba - single)
Computation time: 18.88 ms  (numba - parallel)

# Output (mkl)
Computation time: 34.46 ms  (numpy)
Computation time: 41.82 ms  (numba - single)
Computation time: 28.27 ms  (numba - parallel)
```

1. Am I missing something, i.e., is there some other variable I have to set to restrict the number of threads (OMP_NUM_THREADS is 1)?
2. Is the parallelization itself well designed?